# How do I match an element but avoid failing validation if attributes are present?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

I have the xml:

```
<video contenttype="asf" fileextension=".wmv" hascontent="no" lang="en-GB" length="1800" pid="3678738364972" sid="">
  <title>A vid with Pete</title>
  <description>Petes vid</description>
  <contributor>Pete</contributor>
  <subject>Cat 2</subject>
</video>
```

And I want to validate the video element is present using an xsd schema but I really dont care what attributes it has (in fact I want to ignore the attributes). All I care about is the video element being present. Is it possible to do this with xsd?

Currently the xsd is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema id="UploadXSD"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/UploadXSD.xsd"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/UploadXSD.xsd"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="video">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" minOccurs="1" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="contributor" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="subject" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just specify `xs:anyAttribute` in your `complexType` element, after the sequence: here's [a link](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_anyattribute.asp).